# get content of file with user define in php?

Tags: php, file

I have a file `dict.txt` with its content

```
a
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
b
baa
baaed
baaing
baal
baalism
baalisms
baals
baas
baba
babas
babbitting
babble
babbled
babbler
```

How can I read that file start with `a` or other only.
I know the function file_get_contents will got the string content in file,

```
function getStartWith($letter){
    $allListStartWithWord = array();
    $source = __SITE_PATH."/tmp/wordsEn.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($source );
    $all_list = explode('\n', $content ); // it is big one 
    fclose($fh);
   return $allListStartWithWord;    

}
```

anyone could told me the ways to do that with the large file something like All English Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen(__SITE_PATH."/tmp/wordsEn.txt", 'rb');
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Reads the file line by line

Answer (score 1):

You can't go around reading a line and testing if it starts with an `a`, I can see two solutions to speed up things a little bit:

- If you know that the words are sorted, you can stop when you find a line starting with a `b`
- Write a script to split your file into letter-specific files dict-a, dict-b ... this way you'll only have to read dict-$letter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

a. read the file line by line until you find the character

```
$foundO = false;
while($s=fgets($fh)){
  if(!$foundO && $s[0]!='o') continue; // before O
  if($foundO && $s[0]!='o') break; // after O
  // good line
}
```

or

b. create an index file containing the positions for the starting characters, and use [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

```
$index = file('index.txt');
$pos = $index[ord('O'-65); // 65 is ord('A');
fseek($fh, $pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/SplFileObject) it supports reading a file line-by-line with a simple `foreach`:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($path);
foreach ($file as $line)
{
     ...
}
```

As it offers an iteration over all lines, you can also filter it directly, for example, get all lines starting with `a` and removing the line-breaks:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($path);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);
```

Now, you want to filter the lines, you can just add a filter:

```
$linesStartingWithA = new RegexIterator($file, '/^a/');
```

If you now use `foreach` on the new variable, you will get all lines starting with `a`:

```
foreach ($linesStartingWithA as $line)
{
     ...
}
```

A simple example with the [`SplTempFileObject`](http://php.net/SplTempFileObject) object to demonstrate this (temp-file here because it does not need a physical file on disk then, it is a specific type of `SplFileObject`).

The example ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0mKXB6)):

```
// for the example, a SplFileObject of SplTempFileObject is used.
$file = new SplTempFileObject();
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);
$file->fwrite('a
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
b
baa
baaed
baaing
baal
baalism
baalisms
baals
baas
baba
babas
babbitting
babble
babbled
babbler');

$linesStartingWithA = new RegexIterator($file, '/^a/');

foreach ($linesStartingWithA as $line => $string)
{
    printf("#%d: %s\n", $line, $string);
}
```

Output:

```
#0: a
#1: aah
#2: aahed
#3: aahing
#4: aahs
```